# Update Data view item on custom data view code

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to update the TranDesc field of ARTran, on override code snippet of ARTran in Invoices And Memos page. Here is the full code:

```
[PXOverride]
        public virtual IEnumerable transactions()
        {
            foreach (PXResult<ARTran, SOLine> tran in PXSelectJoin<ARTran, LeftJoin<SOLine,
              On<SOLine.orderType, Equal<ARTran.sOOrderType>,
              And<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<ARTran.sOOrderNbr>,
              And<SOLine.lineNbr, Equal<ARTran.sOOrderLineNbr>>>>>,
            Where<ARTran.tranType, Equal<Current<ARInvoice.docType>>,
              And<ARTran.refNbr, Equal<Current<ARInvoice.refNbr>>>>,
            OrderBy<Asc<ARTran.tranType, Asc<ARTran.refNbr, Asc<ARTran.lineNbr>>>>>.Select(Base))
            {
                if (((ARTran)tran).LineType != SOLineType.Discount)
                {
                    if (((ARTran)tran).TranDesc.Split(':').Length > 1)
                    {
                        using (PXTransactionScope ts = new PXTransactionScope())
                        {
                            string[] desc = ((ARTran)tran).TranDesc.Split(':');
                            ((ARTran)tran).TranDesc = desc[1];
                            Base.Transactions.Cache.IsDirty = true;
                            Base.Transactions.Update((ARTran)tran);
                            Base.Actions.PressSave();
                            Base.Persist();
                            ts.Complete();
                        }

                    }
                    yield return tran;
                }

            }
        }
```

This shows the TranDesc after slicing text before ':', but I want to persist this change to database as well. But the code is not persisting data on database.

Thank you.

Comment: are you trying to simply display a different value or actually persist the change. Doing an update in the view results is a strange place to put an update and even more so for a save and transactionscrope. The goal of the the method you are overriding is just to display the values to the page (which can be changed for display only). Updating value should take place in other areas. Just my thoughts on your question and the posted code being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following code instead of trying to cast the PXResult object to the correct format.
`ARTRan artran = tran.GetItem<ARTran>();
artran.TranDesc = desc[1]; 
Base.Transactions.Update((ARTran)tran);`

`}`
`//outside the for loop`

`Base.Actions.PressSave();`

Also, I would try dropping the PXTransactionScope

Comment: Thank the code works. Though, placing PressSave action out of the loop throws me the overflow exception. I know it definitely is not a good practice to persist item in database for every counter in loop, but placing that PressSave action does the trick. I don't think it could be because of the number of ARTransactions that needs to be updated. I checked the stack trace but couldn't find more than that exception message.